# Django urls -> {n,m} type restriction and .format()

Tags: python, django

i' m trying to have a url pattern which contains a

```
\d{3}
```

type restriction, and a

```
.format()
```

string substitution. Separated they' re working fine, but together doesn' t. The first 2 lines are working, but the problem is the 3rd line:

```
url(r'(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<phase>\w+)/(?P<required_start>\d{3})/$', 'sceduler.views.reserve_slot'),
url(r'(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<phase>{PHASE_STR})/(?P<required_start>\d+)/$'.format(PHASE_STR = PHASE_STR), 'sceduler.views.reserve_slot'),
url(r'(?<Pid>\d+)/(?P<phase>{PHASE_STR})/(?P<required_start>\d{3})/$'.format(PHASE_STR = PHASE_STR), 'sceduler.views.reserve_slot'),
```

.

Any idea how to overcome on this?

Thanks.

Comment: `problem is the 3rd line`, what problem?

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to mention the error message. It' s: 'tuple index out of range' , however it comes from .format(), beucase it tries to use {3}, and doesn' t let it to be processed by the urlresolver. I' d like to workaround this somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing `\d{3}` with `\d{{3}}` should do the trick, but I'm not sure why you're formatting urls like that